# Trouble Binding Data From XML in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I am trying to populate my model with data from an XML file, but have been unsuccessful so far.  Setting a breakpoint at the variable Res shows a null value.

I also tried loading the XML file locally, but the outcome was the same.

I am using VS2013, MVC.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        IQueryable<Restaurant> Res;

        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load
        ("http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles%5CFHRS501en-GB.xml");

        var model =
        from xml in xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail")
        select new Restaurant
        {
            FHRSID = (int)xml.Element("FHRSID"),
            BusinessName = (string)xml.Element("BusinessName"),
            RatingValue = (int)xml.Element("RatingValue"),
            HygieneScore = (int)xml.Element("Hygiene"),
        };

        Res = model.AsQueryable();

        return View(Res);
    }
```

Model:

```
[XmlRoot("EstablishmentDetails")]
public class Restaurant
{

        public int? RestaurantId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("FHRSID")]
        public int FHRSID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("BusinessName")]
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RatingValue")]
        public int? RatingValue { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Hygiene")]
        public int? HygieneScore { get; set; }
 }
```

Sample from the XML file:

```
<FHRSEstablishment>
 <Header>
  <ExtractDate>2014-09-19</ExtractDate>
  <ItemCount>933</ItemCount>
  <ReturnCode>Success</ReturnCode>
 </Header>
 <EstablishmentCollection>
  <EstablishmentDetail>
   <FHRSID>129104</FHRSID>
   <LocalAuthorityBusinessID>5952</LocalAuthorityBusinessID>
   <BusinessName>5 Elm's Cafe</BusinessName>
   <RatingValue>3</RatingValue>
   <Scores>
    <Hygiene>10</Hygiene>
    <Structural>10</Structural>
    <ConfidenceInManagement>10</ConfidenceInManagement>
   </Scores>
  </EstablishmentDetail>
 </EstablishmentCollection>
</FHRSEstablishment>
```

I am quite new to web development in general, this is my first time working with XML files.

New Controller:

```
public class RestaurantController : Controller
{


    public static IEnumerable<Restaurant> GetData()
    {

        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"~/Xml/OpenDataFiles_FHRS501en-GB.xml");



        foreach (var xml in xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail"))
        {

            var eFHRSID = xml.Element("FHRSID");
            var eBusinessName = xml.Element("BusinessName");
            var eRatingValue = xml.Element("RatingValue");
            var eHygieneScore = xml.Element("Scores").Element("Hygiene");
            if (eFHRSID != null && eBusinessName != null && eRatingValue != null           &&             eHygieneScore != null)
            {
                yield return new Restaurant
                {

                    FHRSID = (int)eFHRSID,
                    BusinessName = (string)eBusinessName,
                    RatingValue = (int)eRatingValue,
                    HygieneScore = (int)eHygieneScore,
                };

            }
        }
    }

public ActionResult Index()
    {

     GetData();



    return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defensive programming. Do your null checks or catch exceptions. The 'Hygiene' element is under 'Scores' so 
you need `xml.Element("Scores").Element("Hygiene")` instead of `xml.Element("Hygiene")`. This might be an option:

```
public static IEnumerable<Restaurant> GetData ( )
{
  XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles%5CFHRS501en-GB.xml");

  foreach (var xml in xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail"))
  {
    var eFHRSID = xml.Element("FHRSID");
    var eBusinessName = xml.Element("BusinessName");
    var eRatingValue = xml.Element("RatingValue");
    var eHygieneScore = xml.Element("Scores").Element("Hygiene");
    if (eFHRSID != null && eBusinessName != null && eRatingValue != null && eHygieneScore != null)
    {
      yield return new Restaurant
      {
        FHRSID = (int)eFHRSID,
        BusinessName = (string)eBusinessName,
        RatingValue = (int)eRatingValue,
        HygieneScore = (int)eHygieneScore,
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the nesting in your code example makes sense.  Perhaps as expected I am now getting a null error, specifically "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I have tried a few things such as setting the properties as nullable in the model, and instantiating the variables and assigning some value before they are assigned a value from the XML doc.  But nothing seems to be clearing up the null error. I have added my updated controller to the original question, if that helps.

Comment: You must be able to pinpoint the exact line/member that is null. Use the call stack, stack trace, etc... I see you edited your post in the meantime. Your model has xml serialization attributes. Have you moved from LinqToXml to custom deserialization? Your source xml is successfully parsed with the code in the answer.